# How to sort order of products in website using zen cart

Tags: zen-cart

I am currently developing a website using zen cart and i pretty much have everything done but i am running into a slight problem. When I am putting items up that have numbers in them(ie. 10mm, 20mm) they are not being displayed in the right order. Instead of going

10mm, 20mm....90mm, 100mm, 110mm

it is going

10mm, 100mm, 110mm.....190mm, 20mm, 200mm, 210mm

Does anyone know how to sort this out because it is driving me mad :(

Thank

Answer (score 2):

[This thread on the zen cart forums](http://www.zen-cart.com/forum/showthread.php?t=179344&highlight=sort+number) references the same problem with numerical sorting that you describe. The reply suggests using each product's 'sort' field to override the default sorting.

I would suggest filing a bug report for this issue in their [Bug Report forum.](http://www.zen-cart.com/forum/forumdisplay.php?f=140)